# Conditional Query selection on the basis of paarameters

Tags: oracle

I have two sql:

1st:

```
Select emp.id from Employee
where '&BI'=I
UNION ALL
Select emp.id from Employee
where '&BI'<>I
```

2nd:same as first one but addition of few more tables and more union all

```
(
Select emp.id,sal.salary from Employee emp, Salary sal
where '&BI'=I AND emp.id=100 AND '&BI' Is not null
UNION ALL
Select emp.id,sal.salary from Employee emp, Salary sal
where '&BI'<>I AND emp.id=100 AND '&BI' Is not null
)
UNION ALL
(
Select emp.id,sal.salary from Employee emp, Salary sal
where '&BI'=I AND emp.id=sal.id AND '&BI' Is not null
UNION ALL
Select emp.id,sal.salary from Employee emp, Salary sal
where '&BI'<>I AND emp.id=sal.id AND '&BI' Is not null
)
```

want to combine both 1st and 2nd in to one select statement and run it dynamically.
Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you know what you are doing.

Two things about **query #1**: it is invalid, and it is useless.

What is `emp.`? There's no table alias `emp` there ... It *might* be a function `id` that belongs to package named `emp`, but I somehow doubt it. You probably meant something like

```
select emp.id from employee emp
where ...
```

If that's so, it just doesn't make sense. The way you wrote it, it is equal to

```
select id from employee
```

because the first `SELECT` returns values values "equal" to something, while the second one returns values "different" from that something, and you then `UNION ALL` them. That's the whole contents of the `EMPLOYEE` table.

The first part of **query #2** is wrong as well; you're performing Cartesian product of `employee` and `salary` tables (and then restrict the result with `WHERE` clause). What is

```
and '&BI' is not null
```

condition used for? Did you mean

```
and I is not null
```

instead?

Also, what is `I`? The way you put it, it is a column in one of those tables (probably `employee`, according to query #1). No problem if that's so, it's just that it is somewhat unusual name for a column.

Now, what do you mean by "**combining**" those two queries? How? You can't `UNION` them because their column list doesn't match. What would you combine, then?

Finally, how do you run *anything* **dynamically**? What do you mean by saying that?

Please, provide a **test case** (`create table` & `insert into` sample data), and - using that data - explain the result you'd want to get and rules that should make that happen.